# How should I use maximum likelihood classifier in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification

I am trying to make a program that classifies image into various component like detecting the land, water & sky area. I am at a phase where I have separated RGB values of different area into different classes and stored it in a text file ([See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raAYp.png)) and calculated its mean and variance.

But I am not able to understand how to implement Maximum Likelihood Classifier so I can move forward to classify image.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Logistic Regression is essentially a Maximum Likelihood Classifier.  See the duplicate for more details.  Don't let the title fool you.  The OP has working code, but there are a few things in the accepted answer that are required to get it to work properly.

Comment: @rayryeng hmm, while Logistic Regression and Maximum Likelihood Classifiers (think Bayesian Decision Theory) are related, they are formulated and trained differently (one is a discriminative classifier, the other generative). Think `fitglm` vs. `fitcdiscr`..

Comment: @Amro you're right. In fact Bayesian Decision Theory was the thing I was leaning towards but I couldn't find a good duplicate. Do you have one in mind? I also thought the third column was the class number so I figured it may have been a good duplicate.

Comment: not really no. Personally I always go back to the book "Pattern Classification" by Duda and Hart whenever I need to refresh on Bayesian Decision Theory... Perhaps I can point OP to to online resources like this one: https://www.byclb.com/TR/Tutorials/neural_networks/ch4_1.htm

Comment: @Amro it's a classic book. I use that for Bayesian Decision Theory all the time. Good resource!